# How to get all content before a particular value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one variable named `overall`. This variable has content but I want to get content from a particular string before. I need all the content before 'used' from a string.

```js
var overall = "Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic";
alert(split(overall));

function split(str) {
  var i = str.indexOf("used");

  if (i > 0)
    return str.slice(0, i);
  else
    return "";
} {
  var i = str.indexOf("used");

  if (i > 0)
    return str.slice(0, i);
  else
    return "";
}
```

Comment: `var str = overall.split('used')[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply split by the specific word (`used` in your case), that will return an `array` of two columns:

- The first contains the content before the word
- And the second one contains the last part

Then you could get the first part of the splitted `string` using index `0`, like :

```js
var overall = "Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic";

console.log(overall.split('used')[0]); //Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly 
console.log(overall.split('used')[1]); // in the graphic
```

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Comment: How to remove except that word?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please try to describe more the desired result

Comment: I want to remove all text except used from a string

Comment: Then just use the word directly, `var result = "used"`

Comment: example my output like this  console.log("used")

Comment: No i can not use that..i am fetching datas from a string

Comment: How you fetched the word 'used'?

Comment: Ok, please add more details so I can understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.